# Centos backup at server startup

Tags: backup, bash, rsync, boot, systemd

I wrote [bash script](https://pastebin.com/pJC8iHmS) that make backup of some files from remote folder at system start.

So at system start it mounts remote share in unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=CIFS Share from spr1-backup01
After=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=//192.168.18.12/oracle_backup
Where=/mnt/smb
Type=cifs
Options=ro,vers=2.1,credentials=/root/creds/.cred_oralocalsys

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And after that backup unit is launches (/root/nas/sender.sh is my backup script)

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup oracle database
After=mnt-smb.mount

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/nas/sender.sh
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Probles is if launches automatically at start - it skipping the actual backup process (i mean rsync part in bash script mentioned before).
If i run this script manually - everything will be fine and working as expected.

Any ideas why this happening?

Comment: What can you see in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Is systemd the right tool for the job?  cron lets you specify tasks that should run once on bootup.

```
@reboot  /path/to/job
```

This way the backup runs in parallel with everything else. If the backup is going to take hours to run, running it on every reboot might become an operational nightmare.